# How can I overload = operator for 'MyClass object = f(x)'?

Tags: c++

As in title. 
I have problem with operator overload.

```
int variable = 5;
int* f() {
    return &variable;
}

class MyClass {
    public:
    int* i;
    MyClass operator=(int* j) {
        MyClass x;
        x.i=j;
        return x;
    }
};
```

If I try to make my object like this:

```
MyClass m=f();
```

it doesn't work. But this:

```
MyClass m;
m=f();
```

works...

Comment: Your `operator()` is creating a new `MyClass` and return it. You should mutate the current object.

Comment: I modified it to: `this->i=j; return *this;`. Is it better now?

Comment: @FilipKrawczyk Much better - it should also return by reference otherwise it's still a fresh object you're returning, which breaks chaining in subtle ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first example does not use `operator=` (yes, even though there is a `=` symbol!).

As it is a declaration/definition/initialization, it uses the constructor.

You may create a constructor to do what you need. This ought to be described in your C++ book.

By the way, your `operator=` is implemented weirdly. You're supposed to modify the current object, not create and return a new one. Again, refer to your book for the proper way of doing this.